# Method of Characteristics - Material Derivative of First Order Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I was following a [video lecture on the MoC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mg7shyC9dPM). My understanding is that in general a 2nd order quasilinear PDE can be represented as:

$$
a\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta x^2}+
b\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta x\delta y}+
c\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta y^2}=
d
\tag{1}
$$

If we represented this as a series of 1st order equations

$$
v=\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}, w=\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}
\tag{2,3}
$$

Then (1) is equivalent to

$$
a\frac{\delta v}{\delta x}+
b\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}+
c\frac{\delta w}{\delta y}=
d
\tag{4}
$$

The compatibility equation says that the cross-derivatives are equal

$$
\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta w}{\delta x}=0
\tag{5}
$$

I can take a linear combination of (4) and (5) to get

$$
l_1(\frac{\delta v}{\delta x}+
\frac{b}{a}\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}+
\frac{c}{a}\frac{\delta w}{\delta y})+
l_2(\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta w}{\delta x})
=
\frac{d}{a}
\tag{6}
$$

The logic I am missing is how this is related to the material derivatives of $v$ and $w$. That is,

$$
\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{\delta v}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta v }{\delta y}\frac{dy}{dx}
\tag{7}
$$

$$
\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{\delta w}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta w }{\delta y}\frac{dy}{dx}
\tag{8}
$$

Specifically, in the video I linked (around 27 mins in), the lecturer says that

$$
l_1(4)+l_2(5)=l_1(7)+l_2(8)=\frac{d}{a}
$$

If I knew why that was the case the whole thing would make sense to me, since we can then compare coefficients and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Can anyone explain the link between (4), (5), (7) and (8) that allows us to make that equivalence?